# Orderer does not find channel after restart

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

It seems that my orderers either aren't backing up or I am missing something.

I've got my hyperledger-fabric running by following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/coinmonks/hyperledger-fabric-cluster-on-multiple-hosts-af093f00436) and implemented this backup [strategy](https://medium.com/@jariarud/hyperledger-fabric-backup-and-restore-3263561e259e).

Everything seems to be running fine. But now I want to have some way to recover everything in case of a crash. Killing and restoring peers containers works fine, but it seems that orderers either aren't backing up or I am missing something.

If I kill all docker containers and remove all images.

```sh
docker stop $(docker ps -aq) && docker rm $(docker ps -aq) && docker rmi $(docker images -aq)
```

and then restore it by using docker-compose commands from the mentioned tutorial everything seems to be working fine and I can query assets that were added previously. But adding new transaction fails.

```
docker logs orderer0.example.com
```

shows

```
[channel: mychannel] Rejecting broadcast of normal message from
<my.ip>:39786 because of error:channel does not exist
```

however, if I run

```
docker exec -it cli peer channel list
```

I get

```
Channels peers have joined:
mychannel
```

So how do I connect orderer to the channel again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Hyperledger Fabric does not support backups when using orderers with kafka as of July 2019.

https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-15541